# identifying a subgroup of $S_8$ generated by 4-cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations, rubiks-cube

Let $G \subseteq S_8$ be the subgroup generated by some 4-cycles.  If we number the elements $1,2,\dots, 8$, the 4-cycles are

- $(1234),(5678),(1485),(2376),(1265),(4378)$

I am not sure if I have the list write... I am thinking of the corners of a cube and rotating them. Let me just write the vertices as elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$. What is the order of this group?

These generators are twists of the cube:

- $\boxed{000 \to 001 \to 011 \to 010}$ $\boxed{100 \to 101 \to 111 \to 110}$
- cyclic permutations of these two by $abc \mapsto bca$

What are the relations among these generators to give a [presentation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476854/the-order-of-a-group-presentation)?  In the case of the [dihedral group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798/presentation-of-d-2n) we get some relations like:

$$ D_{2n}= \langle r,s \mid r^{n}=s^{2}=1, rs=sr^{-1} \rangle $$

I am looking something similar for my $G$ generated by 4-cycles.  Or can this group be an action on a vector space?  Right now the twist only works on half the elements.

---

**EDIT** The comments suggest $\mathbf{G = S_8}$.  Can someone find me a way to get a 2-cycle $(12)$ from these 6 elements?

Comment: There are ${8\choose 4}\cdot 3!$ 4-cycles. That is much more than the 6 you've written.

Comment: @tomasz I am asking about the subgroup generated by the six 4-cycles I have listed.

Comment: You should say then that $G$ is the group generated by *these* cycles. Right now it looks like you're saying that $G$ is generated by all 4-cycles and you're attempting to write them all.

Comment: Also, this is certainly not a subgroup of the isometry group of a cube. Any isometry of a cube that fixes $3$ points is constant, while all the 4-cycles will inevitably have $4\geq 3$ fixed points. If anything, you're rotating walls, like $2\times 2\times 2$ Rubik's cube.

Comment: Those six $4$-cycles generate $S_8$.

Comment: @tomasz group $G$ might have an [action](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85308/can-every-group-be-represented-by-a-group-of-matrices/85318#85318) on some other vector space

Comment: @johnmangual: Certainly. Any finite group admits a finite dimensional, faithful representation. But the natural action on ${\bf Z}_2^3$ is certainly not linear, since it has no fixed points.

Comment: @DerekHolt can you find me a word in these generators giving the transposition $(12)$ ?

Comment: If you call the six $4$-cycles $a,b,c,d,e,f$, then $(1,2) = a  c  b^{-1}  d^{-1}  e^{-1}$ (where permutations are composed from left to right).

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your reply.  My main question is about the Cayley graph generated by these 4-cycles, but for today I settled on this easier question I could state more precisely.